# Emacs Recursive Load

Tags: recursion, emacs

I was updating the packages in my `emacs 25.0.50` build. And for some reason it didn't work properly. When I restarted emacs I received the following fatal error message:

> error: Recursive load, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq-25.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq-25.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq-25.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/bytecomp.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq-25.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/elpa/seq-2.15/seq.elc, /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/HEAD/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-extra.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/core/prelude-packages.elc, /Users/Maurice/.emacs.d/init.el

Could anyone explain to me what I should do to rectify this situation?

Comment: And I am using Prelude by b.batsov.... sorry for not mentioning this earlier

Comment: How is the error message unclear?  `cl-extra` pulls in `bytecomp` which pulls in `cl-extra` which pulls in `bytecomp` ...

Comment: The culprit looks like your local `seq` which overrides the Emacs standard `seq` and apparently contains an invalid recursive dependency, but this is speculation.

Comment: So now that you know what the problem is, what would you do to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: If you are still unable to debug this, are you sure Stack Overflow is the right place to ask? Anyway, if your local  `seq` is the culprit, removing that should help (but may cause new symptoms which need to be diagnosed and resolved in turn). As a fallback, try disabling Prelude, or even rename your `.emacs.d` and start over from a clean slate.

Comment: Thanks. I took step number one on my own, and it seemed to work--there is one new symptom, but it isn't too troubling at the moment. I'll see if I can solve that myself.

Comment: I posted a condensed version as an answer -- could you please accept it, so that this question no longer comes up as still requiring an answer? If you don't like mine, post an answer of your own, and accept that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Recursive load" means you have a circular dependency between packages.  `cl-extra` pulls in (by way of `load` or `require`, etc) `seq`, which pulls in `bytecomp`, which pulls in `cl-extra`, which pulls in `seq`, ...

By the looks of it, you have a locally installed third-party packaged version of `seq`, so removing that as the probable culprit seems like the way to go; but there is a reason it's being pulled in, so it's likely that something else stops working because of this change, and so on.

Prelude seems to want this; maybe you'll need to give up on it until this problem has been resolved. (File a bug report if you can!)